# Angularjs - ng-click not firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio

$scope.testing is being added as the button Id correctly but clicking the button doesn't fire the alert.

See example - http://plnkr.co/edit/RtidzgiUI7ZAMOTu3XHy?p=preview

CONTROLLER

```
var app = angular.module('StockCategory', []);

app.controller('stockCategoryController', function($scope) {
  $scope.testing = 'World';

  $scope.saveCategory = function() {

    alert('hello');
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="stock-categories" ng-app="StockCategory" ng-controller="stockCategoryController">
    <button class="btn save-cat" id="{{testing}}" ng-­click="saveCategory();">Save</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: that's really weird not working in plunker or visual sudio

Comment: Should be working, all code looks good. Really weird...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that the button element in your plunker has an extra `-` in your `ng-click` directive. You can't see it in your plunker, try copy and pasting it in an unformatted text editor like notepad. You will see the extra `-` that looks like this:

```
<button class="btn save-cat" id="{{testing}}" ng--­click="doClick()">Save</button>
```

Possible cause would probably be because of copy and pasting code from an html page to another page or from a different document format to an html format.

To solve this, simply create another button element with the same content, don't copy and paste that button element above.

In my **[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/fF0DferH3aBIkCvuhkro?p=preview)** you will see two buttons with the same markup, the first one doesn't work while the other one works perfectly.

Comment: Even copying the code from the question only shows a single dash in plunker but 2 dashes in notepad...... GOOD FIND! By the way, I typed this code myself in visual studio (which only shows one dash as well) and pasted into plunker so no idea how the double dash happened. thats 2 hours of my life I'll never get back.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work fine on [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bic4IGCtDu0EK7dDqddu?p=preview).

I had to make a new one since you were editing the one you posted. It did not look like the code in your question.

Your plnkr had

```
ng-­click="saveCategory"
```

That does not work because `ng-click` expects an expression, not a reference. You had it right in your question.

The code, as it is in your question here works fine.